# Bend a bezier curve along bezier curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I would like to bend a complex bezier curve with a curve modifier.
What do I have to regard in respect to the curve that gives the shape?

Number of control points, location of curve in relation to the curve I want to bend, size of the two curves, etc.? Any hint welcome.

I get only a completely deformed curve.
Thanks!

[image: Bezier curve with 8000 control points]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to perfectly deform a curve with a another curve, no need to convert to mesh first.

But raises the question why. If the second deforming curve already has the desired shape use that one directly.

Curve deformation generally works well on elongated objects that roughly extend in one direction that should run parallel to the length of the curve deforming it.

So if that is the case and the other object is elongated than you probably won't need  second curve to be deformed.

Otherwise it will probably give very weird results. If your curve has a really contorted shape it will probably yield unexpected glitchy-looking deformations.

Things to look out for when using the *Curve Deform* modifier are

- Make sure deforming curve and deformed object are coinciding have exactly the same origin point in the scene's unit coordinates
- Make sure the deforming curve's origin coincides with one its end vertex. In other words one of the end vertex has `0,0,0` local coordinate.
- Make sure the vertex at `0,0,0` is the starting vertex, not the end one.
- Make sure the deformed object has it geometry roughly close or around it's center, or at least sanely placed in relation to it's center (like at one end).
- And lastly make sure the deformed object (the one with the *Curve* modifier) is elongated in the correct direction that runs roughly parallel along the curve length

If not, then you can adjust the deformation axis in the *Curve* modifier properties.

For more complex deformations you may want to look into the *Cast* Modifier, or the *Simple Deform* one, or even the *Shrink Wrap* one.