# Bending curve/object around another object

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, svg

I'm trying to make some 3d fx and I imported my basic svg file. Now I want to wrap it around the top surface of the object but I don't know how. Can somebody help me accomplish this?

[image: My svg which I want to wrap around the top surface of this disk shape]

**Here's how I want it to look like (except not textured):**
[image: Textured version of it]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52904/wrap-curve-around-sphere/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58815/bend-a-bezier-curve-along-bezier-curve/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the *Curve* modifier?

- Create your shape. If it's a svg you'll need to convert it to a mesh and subdivide it a bit. Put its origin on its geometry.

[image]

- Create a curve > circle. Put it at the same point as the shape origin.

[image]

- Give your shape a *Curve* modifier, choose the circle as *Object*.

[image]

- If you think that the shape is not long enough you can either scale the shape (on one axis or on all axis) or scale the circle.

[image]